# Estimate normals for point cloud in Julia

Tags: matlab, julia

Is there an equivalent of MATLAB's [`pcnormals`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcnormals.html) in Julia?

I also would like to know if there is a way to [read](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcread.html) and [write](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcwrite.html) `.ply` files in Julia?

Comment: Have you had a look at [MeshIO.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/MeshIO.jl)?

Answer (score 2):

From the description of `pcnormals` here is an attempt to recreate it using Julia with the aid of the Distances and kNN packages:

```
using Distances
using kNN

function pcnormals(pcloud::Matrix,k::Int = 6)
    n,d = size(pcloud)
    S = pairwise(Euclidean(),pcloud')
    NN = hcat([kNN.k_nearest_neighbors(k,i,S) for i=1:n]...)'
    normals = hcat([normalize(pcloud[[i;NN[i,:]],:]\ones(k+1)) for i=1:n]...)'
    return normals
end

N = 1000
D = 3
X = mapslices(normalize,randn(N,D),2)
normals = pcnormals(X)

println("mean inner product = $(mean(X[1:10,:]*normals[1:10,:]'))")
diag(X[1:10,:]*normals[1:10,:]')
```

The code after the definition is a mini-test which tries to look at points on the unit sphere and see if the normal of a point is close to itself (using inner-product as a similarity measure). The results looked convincing:

```
mean inner product = 0.18584539662300542
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.990708
 0.999839
 0.997276
 0.999705
 0.99959 
 0.999883
 0.999052
 0.998935
 0.9951  
 0.999617
```

So, unless the quick look at `pcnormals` manual page has mislead me, this may be a starting point for a Julia implementation. Note the use of `pairwise` in the code which could be slow for big point clouds.